# Which is the stock symbol of C3.ai?

Tags: stocks, investing, trading

I've been trying to find the stock price & symbol for this company

https://c3.ai

But so far, it's been a fool's errand. There are a few websites which talk about its capitalization, the major investors and so on, but no one is mentioning the stock name: it looks like you have to pay just to get such an elementary information (damn crooks!). Is it because it's not actually a publicly held company?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to have a "market" price and ticker symbol or ISIN (which is what I think you mean by "no one is mentioning the stock name") the stock must be listed on a market. Remember that the stock price is the last price someone paid for it on a stock *market*.

A symbol will be allocated by each stock market it trades on at or just before IPO; there is no need for one pre-IPO as no market data will exist for it. IPO (initial public offering) is the process of putting shares onto the market so until the IPO is complete the shares aren't marketable.

Since there isn't a market price for the stock how you value the stock is part accountancy and part alchemy. Since part of the stock value is share holder equity (= assets - liabilities) this can be calculated. The other part of the value is the net present value (NPV) of future cashflows, to calculate this for a pre-IPO stock you need more of a crystal ball and major guess work than is needed for other stocks as the large players, such as the investment banks, haven't priced it in yet.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer. Yes, I think "ticker symbol" is what I mean by "stock symbol" (mentioned in question title). For example, for Google it's NASDAQ: GOOGL (where NASDAQ is clearly the stock market you were talking about). You say: "Since there isn't a market price for the stock [..]". Are you **sure** about that? Sure, I couldn't find it, but that doesn't mean there isn't one (my search may have been not good enough). I'd like to know for sure if there isn't one, or if I was just not thorough enough in my search.

Comment: Also: since my knowledge of the topic is clearly lacking, can you suggest me resources for the layman (preferably a book, I like to read) to improve my knowledge? I can also open another question if you prefer.

Comment: @DeltaIV if the stock isn't being traded on the market then there is no market price by definition. The definition of market price is the last price at which it was traded on a market. Don't ask a new question for a book recommendation as it will be closed since recommendations of that type are off topic on this site. I'll think of something suitable for you and comment here; I learnt from about 15 years of doing the job!

Comment: " if the stock isn't being traded on the market then there is no market price by definition" ok this is obvious, but what I meant is, are we sure the stock is not being traded on the market? I couldn't find information on whether the company is publicly held or not.

Comment: @DeltaIV according to all sources it is pre-IPO. IPO (initial public offering) is the process of putting shares onto the market so until the IPO is complete the shares aren't marketable. I should have mentioned that that's the way I know it doesn't have shares at market currently.

Comment: Here's a source: See https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/c3. Funding status "Late stage venture".